# LINQ to SQL Cannot detect stored procedure return type

Tags: linq-to-sql, stored-procedures

I have a simple stored procedure that LINQ cannot handle. I have tried variations with and without a temp table, but always get the same result: "The return types for the following stored procedures could not be detected."

Here are the two variations I have tried:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetBOQuestions @JobId int AS
BEGIN
    SELECT  Id, ExemptionCode, Prose [Question], InputType, DisplayOrder
            FROM        Assessor.FLSA.BlackOpsQuestion Q
            LEFT JOIN   Common.dbo.FName F ON F.ajblVIDP = Q.ExemptionCode
            WHERE       ajblERI = @JobId OR Q.ExemptionCode IS NULL
    RETURN 0;
END
```

and...

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetBOQuestions @JobId int AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @TempTable TABLE 
    ( 
        Id VARCHAR(50), 
        ExemptionCode VARCHAR(10),
        Question VARCHAR(1000),
        InputType VARCHAR(20),
        DisplayOrder INT
    ) 
    INSERT INTO @TempTable (Id, ExemptionCode, Question, InputType, DisplayOrder)
    SELECT  Id, ExemptionCode, Prose [Question], InputType, DisplayOrder
            FROM        Assessor.FLSA.BlackOpsQuestion Q
            LEFT JOIN   Common.dbo.FName F ON F.ajblVIDP = Q.ExemptionCode
            WHERE       ajblERI = @JobId OR Q.ExemptionCode IS NULL

    SELECT Id, ExemptionCode, Question, InputType, DisplayOrder FROM @TempTable ORDER BY DisplayOrder
    RETURN 0;
END
```

I have tried this in Linq-to-SQL (.NET 4.0), and in Entity Framework. EF doesn't even see the SP.

Answer (score 3):

For reasons that I forget, Linq-to-SQL will cannot automatically derive the result type from a stored procedure that returns a result set unless you include the following line of T-SQL in your stored proc before dropping it onto the Linq-to-SQL designer:

```
SET FMTONLY OFF;
```

Try this:

1. Insert the code above just after the BEGIN statement in your proc.
2. If you haven't done so already, remove that RETURN 0 as you were previously advised.
3. Execute ALTER for your proc.
4. Refesh your VS.NET Server explorer
5. Drag-and-drop the proc onto your data model designer.
6. When you select your proc in the designer, the Properties pane should display Return Type (Auto-generated Type).
7. Save your data model.
8. Return to your stored proc and comment out the SET command:

   --SET FMTONLY OFF;
9. Execute ALTER for your proc.  Wish I could remember why it is necessary to get rid of it after it has served its purpose.

Answer (score 0):

The line

> RETURN 0

is the culprit in both the cases. Lose it and Linq should be able to detect the types your result set.

Comment: I added it when not having it didn't work either. With or wothout it, LINQ simply can't recognize this simple query.

Answer (score 0):

Linq to Sql won't get the results directly from a Stored procedure. Instead an `ISingleResult` will be returned. You have to enumerate through the result set to get the values returned from the stored procedure.